# Can't figure out which dependencies package spynner 1.11 python 2.7.2 module needs on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, ubuntu-11.10, spynner

I try to install dependencies of [spynner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner) python module, but I get :

```
$ python -c 'import spynner'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spynner-1.11dev-py2.7.egg/spynner/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from browser import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spynner-1.11dev-py2.7.egg/spynner/browser.py", line 35, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, QUrl, QString, Qt, QEvent
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

This is my installed packages matching QT :

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i qt
ii  appmenu-qt                                       0.2.2-0ubuntu1.1                         appmenu support for Qt
ii  ibus-qt4                                         1.3.1-1ubuntu3                           qt-immodule for ibus (QT4)
ii  libibus-qt1                                      1.3.1-1ubuntu3                           qt-immodule for ibus (QT4)
ii  libindicate-qt1                                  0.2.5.91-1ubuntu2                        Qt bindings for libindicate
ii  libpyside1.0                                     1.0.6.1-2ubuntu2                         Python bindings for Qt 4 (base files)
ii  libqt3-compat-headers                            3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu1                       Qt 1.x and 2.x compatibility includes
ii  libqt3-headers                                   3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu1                       Qt3 header files
ii  libqt3-mt                                        3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu1                       Qt GUI Library (Threaded runtime version), Version 3
ii  libqt3-mt-dev                                    3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu1                       Qt development files (Threaded)
ii  libqt4-dbus                                      4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 D-Bus module
ii  libqt4-declarative                               4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 Declarative module
ii  libqt4-designer                                  4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 designer module
ii  libqt4-dev                                       4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 development files
ii  libqt4-help                                      4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 help module
ii  libqt4-network                                   4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 network module
ii  libqt4-opengl                                    4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 OpenGL module
ii  libqt4-opengl-dev                                4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 OpenGL library development files
ii  libqt4-qt3support                                4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 3 compatibility library for Qt 4
ii  libqt4-script                                    4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 script module
ii  libqt4-scripttools                               4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 script tools module
ii  libqt4-sql                                       4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 SQL module
ii  libqt4-sql-mysql                                 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 MySQL database driver
ii  libqt4-sql-sqlite                                4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libqt4-svg                                       4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 SVG module
ii  libqt4-test                                      4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 test module
ii  libqt4-webkit                                    4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       transitional package for Qt 4 WebKit module
ii  libqt4-xml                                       4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 XML module
ii  libqt4-xmlpatterns                               4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 XML patterns module
ii  libqtassistantclient4                            4.6.3-3ubuntu1                           Qt Assistant client library (runtime)
ii  libqtcore4                                       4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 core module
ii  libqtglib-2.0-0                                  0.10.1-2ubuntu3                          C++ bindings library for GLib and GObject with a Qt-style API
ii  libqtgstreamer-0.10-0                            0.10.1-2ubuntu3                          C++ bindings library for GStreamer with a Qt-style API
ii  libqtgui4                                        4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 GUI module
ii  libqtscript4-core                                0.1.0+git20101026+8b191fbc-2             Qt Script bindings for the Qt 4 Core library
ii  libqtscript4-gui                                 0.1.0+git20101026+8b191fbc-2             Qt Script bindings for the Qt 4 Gui library
ii  libqtscript4-network                             0.1.0+git20101026+8b191fbc-2             Qt Script bindings for the Qt 4 Network library
ii  libqtscript4-sql                                 0.1.0+git20101026+8b191fbc-2             Qt Script bindings for the Qt 4 SQL library
ii  libqtscript4-uitools                             0.1.0+git20101026+8b191fbc-2             Qt Script bindings for the Qt 4 UiTools library
ii  libqtscript4-xml                                 0.1.0+git20101026+8b191fbc-2             Qt Script bindings for the Qt 4 XML library
ii  libqtwebkit-dev                                  2.2~2011week36-0ubuntu1                  Web content engine library for Qt - development files
ii  libqtwebkit4                                     2.2~2011week36-0ubuntu1                  Web content engine library for Qt
ii  pinentry-qt4                                     0.8.1-1ubuntu1                           Qt-4-based PIN or pass-phrase entry dialog for GnuPG
ii  pyqt-tools                                       3.18.1-4ubuntu3                          pyuic and pylupdate for Qt3
ii  pyqt4-dev-tools                                  4.8.5-0ubuntu2                           Development tools for PyQt4
ii  python-pyside.qtcore                             1.0.6.1-2ubuntu2                         Qt 4 core module - Python bindings
ii  python-qt4                                       4.8.5-0ubuntu2                           Python bindings for Qt4
ii  python-qt4-dbus                                  4.8.5-0ubuntu2                           DBus Support for PyQt4
ii  python-qt4-dev                                   4.8.5-0ubuntu2                           Development files for PyQt4
ii  python-qt4-gl                                    4.8.5-0ubuntu2                           Python bindings for Qt4's OpenGL module
ii  qdbus                                            4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 Dbus Tool
ii  qt3-dev-tools                                    3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu1                       Qt3 development tools
ii  qt4-designer                                     4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       graphical designer for Qt 4 applications
ii  qt4-linguist-tools                               4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 Linguist tools
ii  qt4-qmake                                        4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1                       Qt 4 qmake Makefile generator tool
```

with `pip` or `easy-install`, that doesn't works :

```
# pip install PyQt
Downloading/unpacking PyQt
  Downloading PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1.tar.gz (9.7Mb): 9.7Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PyQt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sputnick/build/PyQt/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sputnick/build/PyQt/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Log file :

```
# cat /root/.pip/pip.log
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Wed Jun 13 16:00:41 2012
Downloading/unpacking PyQt
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt
  URLs to search for versions for PyQt:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt/
  Getting page http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
  Getting page http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download
  Analyzing links from page http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt/
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/ (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt/); not a file
  Analyzing links from page http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro/index.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/@@/resources/riverbank.css (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .css
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/@@/resources/logo_tn.png (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .png
    Skipping link http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.2/build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .css
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro/@@rcl_login.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://qt.nokia.com (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/commercial/buy (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.sqlite.org (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://webkit.org/ (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://qt.nokia.com/ (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/ (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/developer-tools (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/whitepaper (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://qt.nokia.com/services-partners/partners/partner-directory/riverbank-computing (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/dip-0.4 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .4
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/pyqt-491 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/qscintilla-261 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/sip-4132 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/pyqt-49 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtmobility/download (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/download (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/vendorid/download (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/dip/download (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pykde/download3 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download3 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/download1 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/classes.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/index.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla2/index.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip4/index.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/VendorID/vendorid.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/dip/index.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyKDE3/index.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt3/PyQt.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link mailto:info@riverbankcomputing.com (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro); unknown archive format: .com
  Analyzing links from page http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download/index.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .html
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download/@@rcl_login.html (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .html
    Found link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1.tar.gz (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), version: x11-gpl-4.9.1
    Found link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-win-gpl-4.9.1.zip (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), version: win-gpl-4.9.1
    Found link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.1.tar.gz (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), version: mac-gpl-4.9.1
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/ChangeLog (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); not a file
    Skipping link http://doc.trolltech.com/ (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py3.2-x86-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py3.2-x64-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py3.1-x86-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py3.1-x64-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.7-x64-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.6-x86-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.6-x64-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.5-x86-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.5-x64-gpl-4.9.1-1.exe (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .exe
    Found link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-x11-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581.tar.gz (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), version: x11-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581
    Found link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-win-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581.zip (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), version: win-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581
    Found link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-mac-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581.tar.gz (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), version: mac-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581
    Skipping link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/ChangeLog-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581 (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download); unknown archive format: .2-93480e10d581
  Using version x11-gpl-4.9.1 (newest of versions: x11-gpl-4.9.1, x11-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581, win-gpl-4.9.1, win-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581, mac-gpl-4.9.1, mac-gpl-snapshot-4.9.2-93480e10d581)
  Downloading from URL http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1.tar.gz (from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PyQt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sputnick/build/PyQt/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sputnick/build/PyQt/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 980, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 216, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 255, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

easy_install :

```
#  easy_install PyQt
Searching for PyQt
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt/
Reading http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
Reading http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download
Best match: PyQt x11-gpl-4.9.1
Downloading http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1.tar.gz
Processing PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1.tar.gz
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-kO3Str/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1.tar.gz
```

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner#dependencies said I need pyQt, but I'm pretty sure I don't have anything to compile myself. Any hint ?

Comment: PyQt4 is provided by python-qt4, which is on your list of installed packages. Do you have a PyQt4 folder in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`?

Comment: @Gary Hughes, yes : `# ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/
__init__.py   pyqtconfig.py   QtAssistant.so  QtDeclarative.so  QtGui.so   QtNetwork.so  QtScript.so       Qt.so     QtTest.so    QtXmlPatterns.so  uic
__init__.pyc  pyqtconfig.pyc  QtCore.so       QtDesigner.so     QtHelp.so  QtOpenGL.so   QtScriptTools.so  QtSvg.so  QtWebKit.so  QtXml.so`

Answer (score -1):

I think "sudo apt-get install python-qt4" will solve it.

Comment: `ii  python-qt4                                       4.8.5-0ubuntu2                           Python bindings for Qt4
` if you had read